# Change color if date is weekend using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, unix-timestamp

I have code to check weekend and recolor it.

```
$scope.today = data.getDate() + '/' + (data.getMonth()+1)+ '/' + data.getFullYear();
if($scope.today.getDay() == 6 || $scope.today.getDay() == 0){
    console.log($scope.today+' is Weekend');
    //change color here
    //something like
    //$scope.date.fontcolor("blue");
}
```

HTML code

```
<td>{{today}}</td>
```

data is from datepicker.
And got error

```
TypeError: $scope.today.getDay is not a function
```

Comment: first problem: When you take the date parts then concat them with '/', the resultant is not a Date object, but a string. Strings do not have a "getDay()" function

Comment: second problem: you have control code and DOM manipulation colocated to the same block. This is more likely to cause confusion than prevent it.  Perform your control logic (e.g. Determining what 'today' is) in your controller or in a shared service, then perform your DOM manipulations in a directive.  Rather than setting the color to 'blue', identify the data's pertinent attribute then use css to determine what color that class is to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use Date object.

```
$scope.today = new Date();
if($scope.today.getDay() == 6 || $scope.today.getDay() == 0){
    console.log($scope.today+' is Weekend');
}
```

Then you use [Angularjs filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in your html so you can display the format that you want.

```
<td>{{ today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy }}</td>
```

Second, you can use a flag to check if it is today.

```
$scope.today = new Date();
if($scope.today.getDay() == 6 || $scope.today.getDay() == 0){
    console.log($scope.today+' is Weekend');
    $scope.isWeekend = true;
}
else {
    $scope.isWeekend = false;
}
```

Then you use this flag to control a class for coloring your font using [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

```
<td ng-class="{'weekend': isWeekend}">{{ today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy }}</td>
```

To finish it, you create a CSS for "weekend" class to set the font color as you desire.

```
.weekend {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine, could you help me a little more. I would like to change different color depend on Sat/Sun. What should I change ng-class? 
isSunday and isSaturday: if($scope.today.getDay() == 0){
   $scope.isSunday = true;
    }
   else if ($scope.today.getDay() == 6) {
      $scope.isSaturday = true;
   }
   else {
    $scope.isSaturday = false;
   }

Comment: @AndyJJ then try ng-class="{'saturday': isSaturday, 'sunday': isSunday}"

Answer (score 1):

You first need to properly identify if your date is in a weekend, in order to know this you just need to check the day of the week for the specified date. [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) will return a integer where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday I mention the above because they are the relevant data in your case. Knowing this you could try

```
function isWeekend(date) {
    const day = date.getDay();

    return (day === 0) || (day === 6);
}

const date = new Date('2018-11-26 00:00');

const answer = isWeekend(date);

if (answer) {
    // Change color logic ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay()
if(day == 6 || day == 0) {
    document.getElementById("p1").classList.add("mystyle");
}
document.getElementById("p1").textContent = date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below code snippet. Demo with Jquery UI Date picker

Logic to get weekend

```
var myDate = new Date('2018-11-10');
if(myDate.getDay() == 6 || myDate.getDay() == 0)  console.log('--Weekend ', myDate);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  });  
});


angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('dateCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.isWeekend = false;
   $scope.checkWeekend = function(){
       $scope.myDate = new Date($scope.date);
       if($scope.myDate.getDay() == 6 || $scope.myDate.getDay() == 0) { 
          $scope.isWeekend = true;
          console.log('--Weekend ', $scope.date);
       }else {
          $scope.isWeekend = false;
       }
    };
 
})

.directive("datepicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            el.datepicker({  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.weekend {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="dateCtrl">

   DATE : <input type="text" datepicker ng-model="date" ng-change="checkWeekend()" />
  <span ng-class="{'weekend':  isWeekend }">{{date}}</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```